# What does find() return in \DB\SQL\MAPPER class of fatfree?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I came across this piece of code written by previous developers and I am confused by result of this find() method. It is all gibberish. What does it actually return when no arguments are passed to it?

```
$designation = new DesignationsModel();
$designations = $designation->find();
```

DesignationModel Class is as follows:

```
class DesignationsModel extends \DB\SQL\Mapper {

private $f3;
private static $instance;
protected $_name = 'designations';

 // Instantiate mapper
function __construct() {
    $db = \Base::instance()->get('DB');
    $this->f3 = \Base::instance();
    // This is where the mapper and DB structure synchronization occurs
    parent::__construct($db, $this->_name);
}
```

The result of $designations is used in View as:

```
<select name="designation_id" class="form-control" id="designations">
   <option></option>
     <?php

     foreach ($designations as $designation):
        if (isset($edit)):
          if ($designation->id === $users->designation_id) :
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $designation->id; ?>" selected><?php echo $designation->title; ?></option>
  <?php
          endif;
        endif;
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $designation->id; ?>"><?php echo $designation->title; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: if you don't pass any argument it will return all records from a particular table

Comment: @PankajMakwana Array ( [0] => GBD\Internals\Models\DesignationsModel Object ( [f3:GBD\Internals\Models\DesignationsModel:private] => Base Object ( [hive:Base:private] => Array ( [AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36 [AJAX] => [ALIASES] => Array ( [login] => /login [unauthorized] => /unauthorized [logout] => /logout [user_add] => /user/add [user_save] => /user/save [user_edit] =>

Comment: @PankajMakwana Not just records but too much other information too. Is it expected?

Comment: That is not required information you just need to get those records you returned from the query

Comment: @PankajMakwana thanks :)

Comment: You've put `$this->f3` inside the class, so every object will contain a reference to the framework core - that's why you get all those output information, because you're also dumping the base core.